# Java type erasure

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure

Why is the following snippet printing:

> Constructor class: class java.lang.Integer
> Constructor obj: class java.lang.Integer

I would expect

> Constructor class: class java.lang.Integer
> Constructor obj: class java.lang.Object

because type erasure "replaces" unbound T with object. (java13 in use)

Thank you.

```
public class Test {
    
    public static void main(String... args){
        var g = new TestG<>(Integer.class, 2);
        g.print();
    }
}

public class TestG<T> {

    private final Class<T> clazz;
    private final T obj;

    public TestG(Class<T> clazz, T obj) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
        this.obj = obj;
    }

    public void print(){
        System.out.println("Constructor class: " + clazz);
        System.out.println("Constructor obj: " + obj.getClass());
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider `Object o = 2; System.out.println(o.getClass());`. What do you expect the output to be?

Comment: I expected Object, but realized it's Integer

Comment: So, do you now realise that this actually has nothing to do with type erasure? `getClass` will get the _runtime_ type of the object no matter what.

Comment: Make this as an answer, we can close this..

Answer (score 1):

Considering:

```
Object o = 2; 
System.out.println(o.getClass());
```

one sees that `.getClass()` returns the runtime type, which is Integer.
So, this question actually has nothing to do with type erasure.
This answer was given by Sweeper.